# Getting XLS formula into SQL for Quarter/Yearly returns data

Tags: sql, t-sql

Need your help with automating one report which is manually created in xls

I have automated the data generation of the report i.e monthly generated of returns .

```
ROW in XLS     DATE     RETURN
B75             1/31/2014   -0.5%
B76             2/28/2014   1.36%
B77             3/31/2014   1.4%
B78             4/30/2014   1.00%
B79             5/31/2014   3.76%
B80             6/30/2014   2.43%
B81             7/31/2014   1.42%
B82             8/31/2014   0.61%
B83             9/30/2014   -2.61%
```

This data would be expanded every time for each quarter on quarter.Please suggest ideas to calculate following on the report.
Currently the report has a formula

1. Quarter #  returns - If the report is run for Q3 then show the returns for Q3 with the formula 
   =PRODUCT(1+B81:B83)-1
   where B81 and B83 are the rows 
   One option is to use a query to return the data 
   or have a macro in xls which would take the run date of the quarter and fetch the right value
2. 3 year return
   =PRODUCT(1+B48:B83)^(12/COUNT(B48:B83))-1
3. 12 month return  - This solution would be same as quarter solution
   =PRODUCT(1+B72:B83)-1

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to the 3 problem where I need to return Annual return

SELECT  datepart(yyyy, price_date) as [year],   EXP(
            Sum(
            IIf(Abs(return)=0,0,LOG(Abs(return)))))*
            IIf(Min(Abs(return))=0,0,1)*
            (
            1- 2*(
            Sum(IIf(return>=0,0,1)) % 2
            )) AS P FROM @returnTable WHERE GROUP BY datepart(yyyy, price_date)

In the above query

SQL statement, contains three parts (multipliers).
The first and the second  are capable of handling positive numbers and zeros. Third multiplier is added to take care of the sign by counting negative numbers, then dividing it by Modulo 2 and subtracting the doubled result value from 1. In simple words, it returns 1 for even count and -1 for odd count of all negatives, if any.

Any pointers how to get the Quarterly and 3 yearly return.Thanks for helping out